# fixing the ambiguity around the Salesforce1 tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Although that Salesforce1 indeed spans more then just the mobile app, more then 90% of the questions that are posted around Salesforce1 are about the actual mobile app.

Lately, it happens more and more that questions are linked to the Salesforce1 tag while it is not related to the mobile app at all. But given the current tag wiki and also just the overall ambiguity around Salesforce1 as a term, I can see why some people would also link their question so Salesforce1.

It would be my suggestion that the existing Salesforce1 tag is renamed to (for example) Salesforce1-app . Or at least to something making it clear that the tag is to be used for the Salesforce1 mobile app.

For Salesforce1, I think that is really to broad to be a tag since it's more the new branding and way of thinking at Salesforce.

Comment: I think the problem is more about the wiki for the tag, and not the tag itself. Salesforce1 is a suite of technologies, to be sure, but I don't want to see twenty different salesforce1-* tags, which could happen. Salesforce1-visualforce, Salesforce1-customization, salesforce1-api, salesforce1-javascript, salesforce1-jquery... If something isn't Salesforce1, remove the tag. For everything else, use multiple tags, as appropriate. That's just my two cents, though.

Comment: I can see your point but don't fully agree though. There are multiple mobile apps out there as a starter. You have for example the Salesforce classic app, the Touch app, the Salesforce1 app etc. All current questions were talking about the Salesforce1 app. I don't see the point in creating specific tags for (for example) salesforce1-api or salesforce1-mobile as Salesforce1 isn't something you can grasp, it's just the new way of thinking at Salesforce. That's like there is a tag called salesforce-crm. It's widely used but wildly to broad as well and marked for removal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree - salesforce1 as a tag is way too broad. For now, I've aliased it to salesforce1-app and retagged all the existing questions.

Comment: I don't think that's necessarily appropriate. Salesforce1 may be a "meta-tag", but there's nothing wrong with that *per se*, so long as it is not abused. For example, if someone tags a question "java soap", there's little question about the content of the question, and invites both Java developers and SOAP experts to jump in. "Salesforce1 mobile" makes sense, as does "Salesforce1 visualforce", as well as "Salesforce1 customization". Using a tag like "Salesforce1-app" invites further tag fragments: "Salesforce1-api", "Salesforce1-visualforce", etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this change, broad tags are perfectly acceptable IMO, like API and Apex.